# Gets a list of the folders for the account not listing user defined folder [docusignapi]

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to get all folder using docusign folder API.

**Request Url** : {{baseUrl}}/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/folders?sub_folder_depth=-1

**Response only contains** : Inbox,Sent,Drafts and Deleted

I am also expecting the test1_folder that I created under 'Folders'

[image]

[docusignapi]

Answer (score 0):

I tried this call just now. All the custom folders I created are listed as subfolders under Inbox with further nesting if they have subfolders within as well. It is likely that your response is also returning it the same way.

If it is not, please open a case with [DocuSign Developer Support](https://support.docusign.com/s/contactSupport?language=en_US&Channels=7) to examine this further.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply and link to the support. I double checked and I don't have the custom folders in my response.

Comment: Any update about this? I'm facing same problem using C# SDK

Comment: now I got it, inside of inbox folder you have custom ones..

``` "folders": [
    {
      "name": "Draft",
      "type": "draft",
      "itemCount": "1",
      "hasSubFolders": "false"
    },
    {
      "name": "Inbox",
      "type": "inbox",
      "itemCount": "0",
      "hasSubFolders": "true",
      "folders": [
        {
          "name": "Project Fair",
          "type": "normal",
```